# Deklinierung von Kreis im Sinne einer Gebietskörperschaft

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive, declension

Wie wird der Kreis im Sinne eines Kreises als Körperschaft (räumliche Einteilung von Regierungsbezirken) dekliniert, wenn die konkrete Körperschaftsbezeichnung folgt?

Insbesondere beim Genitiv komme ich ins Stocken. Beispiel:

> A) Die Kreisverwaltung des Kreises Steinfurt.
> B) Die Kreisverwaltung des Kreis Steinfurt.

Ich weiß, dass im Sinne der regulären Deklination des Wortes Kreis Option A korrekt ist, bemerkte aber, dass ich im Sprachgebrauch Option B nutze und diese für mich sinnhafter wirkt. Ohne den Anhang Steinfurt würde ich aber immer sagen/schreiben

> Die Kreisverwaltung des Kreises

Comment: Im Allgemeinen: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Genitiv-auf-s-oder-es Im Speziellen: https://www.duden.de/deklination/substantive/Kreis und https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kreis

Comment: Diese Grundregeln sind mir alle durchaus bewusst, mir geht es aber speziell um den Fall, wenn danach noch der Kreisname steht.

Comment: Der dritte Link von Roland (zu dwds) enthält zumindest das Beispiel _der Rat des Kreises N_

Comment: Ich habe noch keine Antwort darauf. Aber vielleicht findest du etwas unter dem Stichwort _Erweiterungsnomina_- Ich selbst habe erst mal nur das hier gefunden: https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1642

Comment: @e-shirt: hast du denn bei vergleichbaren Konstruktionen auch ähnliche Zweifel? "Das Auto des Herrn Mayer"? ["Die Verwaltung des Bezirks Unterfranken"](https://www.bezirk-unterfranken.de/ueberuns/verwaltung/index.html)? "Die Regierung des Landes Schleswig Holstein"? Ich würde mich wundern, wenn irgendeine Grammatik explizit für "Kreis" darauf eingeht, und ich frage mich, was für eine Art von Begründung du als Antwort ansehen würdest.

Comment: Google: (ja, ich weiß.) "Amtsblatt des Kreises": 41.000 Ergebnisse; "Amtsblatt des Kreis": 4.700 Ergebnisse. Beides scheint zumindest im Gebrauch zu sein, wenn auch bei weitem nicht gleich häufig.

Comment: Wieso wurde mein Kommentar gelöscht? @jnathanscholbach?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich habe deinen Kommentar gelöscht, weil ich ihn als eine Antwort auf die Frage wahrgenommen habe. Die sollten als Antwort gepostet werden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wann etwas zu deklinieren ist (das dazugehörige Nomen lautet übrigens "Deklination", nicht "Deklinierung", aber das nur nebenbei), hängt davon ab, wie genau man eine Fügung verstanden haben will. Ein Beispiel für was ich meine:

Eine (hypothetische) Person heiße "Maier" und sei Präsident (wovon auch immer). Würde man nun "Präsident Maier" im Genitiv benutzen, dann käme es erstens darauf an, ob man "Präsident Maier" als Eigennamen von etwas oder jemanden auffaßt oder nicht und zweitens, welcher Teil der Fügung "Präsident Maier" als wichtig(er) empfunden wird:

> Die Tasche des Präsident*en* Maier ...

oder:

> Die Meinung Präsident Maier*s*

Im letzten Falle wird "Maier" (also die Person) als das Bestimmende aufgefaßt und deshalb mit der Genitiv-Endung "s" versehen, während in ersten Fall "Präsident" das Bestimmende ist und "Maier" lediglich spezifiert, um welchen der Präsidenten es sich handelt.

hingegen (Eigennamen-artig):

> Folgen des Präsident-Maier-Erlass*es* sind ...

Daraus folgt: wenn "Kreis Steinbach" als Eigennamen-artige Fügung verstanden wird, dann sollte die Deklination unterbleiben, etwa so:

> Das Büro der Kreisverwaltung Kreis Steinbach ...

Hier ist "Kreis Steinbach" eine Art Name, mit der ebenjene Kreisverwaltung bezeichnet wird.

Wenn aber der Eigenname "Steinbach" lautet und lediglich spezifiziert, um welchen der in Frage kommenden "Kreise" es sich handelt, dann sollte das bestimmende "Kreis" auch dekliniert werden:

> Die Verwaltung der Kreise Steinbach, Dortheim und Dahausen ...

Hier ist von "Kreisen" die Rede und die Eigennamen spezifizieren lediglich, welche genau.

> Das Büro der Kreisverwaltung des Kreises Steinbach ...

Ist aber "Steinbach" der bestimmende Teil, dann wir dieser Name auch dekliniert:

> (Kreis) Steinbachs Kreisverwaltung ist ...

Das "Kreis" könnte hier auch weggelassen werden, es spezifiziert lediglich, was "Steinbach" eigentlich ist.

Comment: Die Folgerung wäre also, dass es strenggenommen, wenn man das Wort "Kreis" hier nicht beugen möchte, "Die Verwaltung Kreis Unterfranken**s**" heißen müsste. Ohne Artikel, denn "Kreis Unterfranken" ist dann ein Name.

Comment: Ich finde die Differenzierung gut, sie scheint mir in die richtige Richtung zu gehen. Dennoch zeigt der Kommentar von HalvarF eine Inkonsistenz in der Argumentation auf. Lässt die sich ausbügeln? Dann wäre es für mich eine überzeugende Antwort.

Comment: @HalvarF: _Eigenname_ heißt nicht automatisch, dass es keinen Artikel gibt (_**die** Schweiz_, aber _Österreich_, _**die** Toten Hosen_, aber _Sportfreunde Stiller_), ich denke, dass _die Verwaltung des Kreis Unterfranken_ im Sinne der Fragestellung ebenfalls möglich wäre. Das Problem: Bei bestimmten Eigennamen **kann** einer der Namensbestandteile (auch) als Gattungsname (= nicht-eigennamig ) interpretiert werden. Das führt zu Unklarheiten und Widersprüchlichkeiten bei Beugung, Kongruenz, Artikelgebrauch und Großschreibung, bei denen sich oft kein eindeutiger Sprachgebrauch durchsetzt.

Answer (score 0):

Die etablierte und regelgerechte Ausdrucksweise ist

- Das Krankenhaus des Kreises Erlangen
- Im Wirtschaftsausschuss des Landkreises Unterallgäu

Den Kreis hier nicht zu deklinieren, wäre eine recht unübliche Ausdrucksweise.

Allerdings muss ich zugeben, dass ich gelegentlich auch schon Formulierungen getroffen habe, die die Deklination weglassen:

- Für die Einwohner des Landkreis Biberach (gegenüber "des Landkreises Biberach")

Das mag sogar in einer Lokalzeitung gewesen sein. Ich würde das Weglassen der Kasusendung für den Genitiv hier aber eher als schlechte Praxis bezeichnen, ja, als Schludrigkeit. Auch Zeitungsredaktionen sind nicht frei von Schludrigkeiten, vor allem, wenn durch zu engen Kontakt mit Verwaltungsmenschen deren Sprachmarotten unbemerkt übernommen werden.

Comment: Eine Begründung würde die Qualität der Antwort erhöhen. Bei normativen Fragen in der Sprache sind alle Autoritäten relativ. Daher empfiehlt sich immer, die Autorität anzugeben, auf die man sich stützt. Damit wird klar, welche Reichweite und Geltungskraft die Norm hat. Ein Beispiel: Es ist für Sprachverwender:innen ein Unterschied, ob eine sprachliche Regel A) im Duden steht, B) in der Schule gelehrt wird, C) in einem Gesetz oder einer Verodnung für den Behördengebrauch geregelt ist oder D) meiner privaten Auffassung von Richtigkeit entspricht. Je deutlicher eine Antwort hier ist, desto besser.

Comment: Sorry, lieber Jonathan, die "Autorität" bin in diesem Falle leider nur ich selbst. Ich war lange genug Redakteur einer Tageszeitung in Deutschland. Wem das nicht reicht, der möge eine quantitative Analyse der Ausdrucksweisen im deutschsprachigen öffentlichen Raum zum Anwenden oder Weglassen der Genitivendung beim Wort "Kreis" im Sinne von "Landkreis" suchen oder selbst unternehmen.

Comment: Im Allgemeinen ist die individuelle persönliche Meinung eine Auskunft mit relativ schwacher Aussagekraft. Das persönliche Sprachgefühl ist immer von Regio- und Soziolekt geformt - für die Leser:innen hier ist aber nicht ersichtlich welchen Hintergrund die User:innen haben, die ihre Meinung posten, sodass sie die Meinung nicht gut einordnen können. Ich weiß, manchmal gehts nicht besser. Im speziellen Fall aber könnte man schon mehr dazu finden. Und dann kommt noch hinzu, dass dein Beitrag nicht erklärt, wie es kommt, dass die Version durchaus verwendet wird. Daher habe ich hier -1 gegeben.

Answer (score -1):

Option A ist richtig.
Option B ist nicht nur grammatikalisch falsch, sondern widerstrebt auch völlig meinem Sprachgefühl und ist mir so in freier Wildbahn auch bisher nicht begegnet.

Comment: eine in meinen Augen nicht sehr zielführende Antwort mit einer latenten Beleidigung im Unterton brauche ich nicht unbedingt...

Comment: Eine Begründung würde die Qualität der Antwort erhöhen. Bei normativen Fragen in der Sprache sind alle Autoritäten relativ. Daher empfiehlt sich immer, die Autorität anzugeben, auf die man sich stützt. Damit wird klar, welche Reichweite und Geltungskraft die Norm hat. Ein Beispiel: Es ist für Sprachverwender:innen ein Unterschied, ob eine sprachliche Regel A) im Duden steht, B) in der Schule gelehrt wird, C) in einem Gesetz oder einer Verodnung für den Behördengebrauch geregelt ist oder D) meiner privaten Auffassung von Richtigkeit entspricht. Je deutlicher eine Antwort hier ist, desto besser.

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen/

Comment: Zur "freien Wildbahn": Internetsuche nach "des Kreis ..." mit einem Kreis X führt schnell zu Ergebnissen. Etwa hier: https://www.kennzeichenking.de/landkreise/kreis-leipzig/zulassungsstelle für "des Kreis Leipzig": _Nutzen Sie hierzu die Terminreservierungs-Plattform des Kreis Leipzig._

Comment: @e-shirt Ein latenter Unterton war von mir nicht beabsichtigt, schon gar kein beleidigender. Wenn du mir mitteilt, was an meiner Antwort bei dir diesen Eindruck erweckt, ändere ich das gerne.