# Beugung von zusammengesetzten Eigennamen im Genitiv

Tags: genitive, compound, proper-noun

Wie geht man mit zusammengesetzten Eigennamen (zum Beispiel Vereins- oder Firmennamen) um, wenn sie im Genitiv stehen?

Bei normalen Substantiven wird neben der Beugung des Hauptwortes auch der Artikel ins Genitiv gesetzt ("das Hotel" => "des Hotels"). Bei "einfachen" Eigennamen scheint es auch zulässig zu sein, nur den Artikel ins Genitiv zu setzen ("der Rückspiegel des Audi").

Aber was ist mit *zusammengesetzten* Eigennamen, wie zum Beispiel "Deutsches Rotes Kreuz"? Die scheinbar gängigste Form ist "des Deutschen Roten Kreuz", aber kann es richtig sein, das Wort "Deutsches" zu beugen, aber nicht "Kreuz"? Ich habe Meinungen gehört, dass Eigennamen grundsätzlich nicht gebeugt werden, aber "Der Vorstand des Deutsches Rotes Kreuz" hört sich einfach falsch an.

Gibt es dafür eine feste Regel?

Comment: Wo hast du denn "des Deutschen Roten Kreuz" gefunden? Ich kenne auch nur "des Deutschen Roten Kreuzes". Beispiel: https://www.drk.de/presse/pressemitteilungen/meldung/vorbereitung-auf-komplexe-krisen-drk-laedt-zur-fachtagung-katastrophenvorsorge-25-27okt/  "Die diesjährige Fachtagung Katastrophenvorsorge des Deutschen Roten Kreuzes (DRK) widmet sich ..."

Comment: @HalvarF Zum Beispiel https://www.drk.de/das-drk/drk-verbandsstruktur/ – "Der hauptamtliche Vorstand des Deutschen Roten Kreuz e. V. ..." Die sind sich selbst nicht sicher :)

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70559/deklinierung-von-kreis-im-sinne-einer-gebietsk%c3%b6rperschaft

Comment: Es gibt bei Sprachen grundsätzliche Probleme mit der Frage nach Regeln. Der folgende Meta-Thread beschäftigt sich damit eingehender: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen

Comment: @fbitterlich Ja, denn wenn man dem Link zu Seite dieses Vorstandes folgt, findet man es da im selben Satz wieder korrekt gebeugt. Ich vermute, dass es in dem Fall dass "e.V." ist, das für Verwirrung sorgt,.

Comment: @HalvarF Der vollständig Eigenname ist "Deutsches Rotes Kreuz e. V.", wobei "e. V." für "eingetragener Verein" steht. Das Genitiv-s fehlt, weil "Vereins" abgekürzt wurde.

Answer (score 4):

Nun, eigentlich ist es ganz einfach:

> Die Schreibung von Eigennamen und davon abgeleiteten Wörtern richtet sich grundsätzlich nach den allgemeinen Rechtschreibregeln.

Das betrifft u.a. auch die Flexion. Damit scheint nur

> des Deutschen Roten Kreuzes

richtig zu sein - und damit hat sich deine Frage eigentlich erübrigt, weil sie von falschen Voraussetzungen ausgeht.

Und: *Natürlich* müssen Eigennamen flektiert werden - ansonsten droht Sinnverlust im Satz.

Comment: 1) Ist die angegebene Regel ein Zitat? Wenn ja, was ist die Quelle? 2) Wieso ist eine Regel in Bezug auf die Schreibung relevant, wenn es um Flexion geht? 3) Welcher Sinnverlust entsteht z.B. bei *der Rückspiegel des Audi*?

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen

Comment: @DavidVogt https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Die-Deklination-von-Firmennamen
Was deine andere Frage bezüglich des Sinnes angeht, hier ein Beispiel:
Joachims Auto. Joachim Auto.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn ein Eigenname Nomen oder Adjektive enthält, müssen diese alle passend gebeugt werden.

> Deutsches Rotes Kreuz — das Deutsche Rote Kreuz, des Deutschen Roten Kreuzes, dem Deutschen Roten Kreuz, das Deutsche Rote Kreuz

Es gibt nur wenige Ausnahmen, insbesondere wenn der Artikel zu einem Teil des Namens geworden ist.

> in „Der Spiegel“ stand drin …

> die Redaktion von „Der Spiegel“ aus Hamburg

wobei auch da die gebeugte Variante weitaus häufiger ist

> im „Spiegel“ stand drin …

> die Redaktion des „Spiegels“ aus Hamburg

Comment: "von "Der Spiegel""

Das ist kein Genetiv.

Comment: It applies to all cases. That's why I introduced dative as well.

Comment: I would say it's generally wrong to say "...von Der Spiegel", because genitive is the appropriate usage here, not dative. The only two possibilities are "...Des Spiegels" or "...Des Spiegel".
The usage of dative with "von" instead of genitive is maybe ok in colloquial, but not in formal language. 
https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Die-Deklination-von-Firmennamen

Comment: As I wrote, “Der Spiegel” is an exception because the article is a part of the name.

Comment: But you did not prove it. The linked articel is quite clear about this topic in my eyes:
"Namen von Unternehmen/Firmen werden ganz normal dekliniert (gebeugt):"
This exception you are talking about is not mentioned there. 
You do not even post any links etc. where this exception is used.

Comment: But you realize Duden isn't an authoritative source on the German language but the people using it are? If they missed that, its their fault.

Comment: It's not, but it's reasonable to assume that they are right until it was proved otherwise. It's rather correct than what you said without any evidence whatsoever. For example, many people use Dative when Genitive should be used, it is still considered gramatically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Language is to be spoken (used).

Said that, any ruleset is not defined by some Books etc. (not even by the holy Bible "Duden" ;-) ).

Any Book that explains the rules of the language do not define those rules, but represent the current rules (the causality is key) of the used language. But you can assume that "Duden" for example does summarize the current state of the language pretty well.

According to "Duden", the current standard is to say:
"...des Deutschen Roten Kreuzes..."
or if you want to let the original name untouched, you can say:
"... des Vereins Deutsches Rotes Kreuz..."

https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Die-Deklination-von-Firmennamen

Comment: Interesting that you're saying "Duden doesn't..." in your second paragraph, then cite Duden in your fourth.

Comment: @tofro I suggest you to read carefully what I wrote.